# Dynamically updating a marker in Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm sorry to post such a seemingly dumb question, but how do I go about dynamically updating a map marker without user interaction? What I have in mind something like Uber, where you see on the map a marker representing a car which moves on the map based on gps coordinates it is receiving from some server somewhere.

I have never worked with dynamic real time data so I'm not sure what is the proper Android paradigm to be using.

I have a web app currently generating GPS coordinates. I want my app to be constantly polling my web server for updated coordinates and then moving an existing marker on my android app based on those coordinates.

How do I go about doing this? AsyncTask? A service? a while loop!?!

Thank you for any pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` isn't really suited for this kind of task. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.)

For the scenario you describe, there are two possible solutions that would be a better fit: either a long-running Thread, or a Service. A service would be especially useful if you want this polling to continue even if the application is currently in the background (which, however, wouldn't seem to be the case here).

I would recommend creating a new Thread when you create the activity or fragment, and run a poll/sleep loop. Be sure to interrupt this thread whenever the Activity is paused (in `onPause()`), and resume it in `onResume()`. Also, be sure to update the `MapView` only from the UI thread -- this is a requirement in Android programming. You can use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to do this.

Be mindful that constant polling can cause a significant impact on battery life. Depending on the update frequency and other criteria, you may consider alternatives (such as using GCM). I recommend you take a look at the ["Transferring Data Without Draining the Battery" section of the training docs](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html).